# How to compare two field in aggregation filter in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
{
   side1:"apple",
   side2:"peach",
   a1:[
      {_id:"apple", info:"test"},
      {_id:"orange", info:"test"},
   ],
   a2:[{_id:"banana", info:"test"},
      {_id:"peach", info:"test"},
      {_id:"apple", info:"test"}]
}
```

I'm looking for a way to list only subdocuments of `a1` and `a2` which their `_id` values are respectively equal to `side1` and `side2`.
I mean the result should be the following :

```
{
   side1:"apple",
   side2:"peach",
   a1:{_id:"apple", info:"test"},
   a2:{_id:"peach", info:"test"}
}
```

I googled a lot and I have read about `$filter`, `$elemMatch` and `$where` but I could not use them to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aggregation pipeline like this

```
db.getCollection('yourColl').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            side1: 1,
            side2: 2,
            a1: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$a1",
                    as: "e",
                    cond: { 
                        $eq: ["$$e._id", "$side1" ]
                    }
                }
            },   
            a2: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$a2",
                    as: "e",
                    cond: { 
                        $eq: ["$$e._id", "$side2" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

would have this output for your sample data

```
{
    "side1" : "apple",
    "side2" : "peach",
    "a1" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "apple",
            "info" : "test"
        }
    ],
    "a2" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "peach",
            "info" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```